# Apex batch execution in Partner Professional edition for managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, appexchange, professional-edition

We have an app which is listed on AppExchange which passed the security review.

There is an issue only in **Partner Professional** edition when the app executes an **Apex batch** from LWC.
The error: "**apex://ClassName: No apex action available for ClassName.methodName**"
In all other editions it works just fine.

I did not find any documentation which says that PE cannot execute batches.
For testing purposes I installed another app from AppExchange which executes batches. I see them in Apex Jobs. Could you advice how to fix it or troubleshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by itself after Salesforce SU'21 release. No changes were made from my side